Sharing links normally for logged in user RLS policy
I want to create a new feature in a mobile app that allows sharing of certain app routes/links. Typically, the person who creates or views the data is the logged in user. But I want to allow sharing of certain pages now to users who may not be logged in.
What kind of RLS policy would be best to support this? Do I need to generate tokens as part of the URL; but i would need to store those tokens somewhere for an undetermined amount of time? Other suggestions to allow for data tables that normally are for logged in user RLS, but not make public?
